# Change name of author on tracked changes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to change the author name on tracked changes in a selection in MS Word.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Sub ChangeTracksBySingleAuthor()

    Dim J As Integer
    Dim sAuthorname As String
    Dim sOrigAuthorname As String

    If Selection.Range.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No changes in your selection!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Cannot perform action"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sOrigAuthorname = InputBox("Author name to change", "Changes Author Name")        
    If sOrigAuthorname = "" Then End

    sAuthorname = InputBox("New author name", "Changes Author Name")        
    If sAuthorname = "" Then End

    With ActiveDocument
        For J = 1 To .Revisions.Count
            If .Revisions(J).Author = sOrigAuthorname Then                
                .Revisions(J).Author = sAuthorname
            End If
        Next J
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: [Returns the name of the user who made the specified tracked change. **Read-only String**.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837934.aspx) - seems rewriting history isn't allowed.

Comment: I have had problems with the first approach suggested in the accepted solutions (Editing the XML): Using four different zip/unzip tools, I have followed the approach of the accepted solution, however, after re-zipping the edited xml file, Word would always complain about a corrupted file. Using the slightly different approach suggested by user1912526 (save as Word xml file rather than docx) not only saves the unzipping/rezipping steps, but it also worked flawlessly on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to change the author of a revision afterwards using VBA. You might be able to change the author beforehand, or you could use one of the following ways:

#### Edit Open XML

1. Save your document as a .docx file.
2. Then open the file using a zip tool such as 7-zip.
3. Navigate to `word\document.xml` (or whatever part of the document the revision is in, e.g. header, footer, footnote, endnote, ...), right-click and choose *Edit*
4. Search and replace the author name and save the changed file to the zip package

#### Using Word Compare

The following method uses Word compare to set the author of all revisions to a specific author (however, be aware that this method generates completely new revisions that might (slightly) differ from your original revisions):

1. Save a copy of the original document, name it V1, and reject all changes in it.
2. Save another copy of the original document, name it V2, and accept all changes in it.
3. Open V1 in Word > Review tab > Compare > Compare.
4. In the "Compare Documents" dialog, navigate to and select V1 as the original document, and then V2 as the revised document; type the desired author name after “Label changes with”; after “Show changes in,” select “New document,” then click OK.

Comment: "Edit Open XML" worked for me on a big, complex document.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: This is a very old question but this seems to come up A LOT from googling and no-one has provided a solution here or anywhere else, so I am adding mine.

I am a near-complete novice at coding of any sort but a pretty quick/intuitive study and I've been hacking away at this problem as one of my first projects.

I think I have a solution, which conceptually works by taking all revisions with a specific author, storing them in collections, rejecting them in the body of the selection, changing username, then re-implementing the changes as new amendments to the document (thus creating new revisions with the new author).   Here's my code, which I unfortunately can't test as my work PC has authors locked as a security policy.  Please let me know if you see this and it works.

```
Sub ChangeRevisionAuthor()

Dim sCurrentAuthor As String
Dim sOldAuthor As String
Dim sNewAuthor As String
Dim sRevision As String

Dim TCStatus As Boolean

Dim myRange As Range
Dim revRange As Range

Dim myRev As Revision

Dim cIns As New Collection
Dim cDel As New Collection

If Selection.Range.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No track-changes in your selection!", _
      vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Cannot perform action"
    Exit Sub
End If

sOldAuthor = InputBox("Old author name?", _
  "Comments Old Author Name")
If sOldAuthor = "" Then End

sNewAuthor = InputBox("New author name?", _
  "Comments New Author Name")
If sNewAuthor = "" Then End


BCStatus = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
sCurrentAuthor = Application.UserName

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True

Set myRange = Selection.Range


For Each myRev In myRange.Revisions

    If myRev.Author = sOldAuthor Then
        If myRev.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
        cIns.Add myRev
        End If
        If myRev.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
        cDel.Add myRev
        End If
    End If

Next

Application.UserName = sNewAuthor

For Each myRev In cIns
    Set revRange = myRev.Range
    myText = revRange.Text
    myRev.Reject
    revRange.InsertAfter myText
Next

For Each myRev In cDel
    Set revRange = myRev.Range
    myRev.Reject
    revRange.Delete
Next

Application.UserName = sCurrentAuthor
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = BCStatus

End Sub
```

Comment: IMHO the only sensible answer to the original question. Works well in our environment. Check possible types of `Revision.Type` for your requirements

Comment: This is excellent.  Thank you, AB9000.  A few wrinkle to be aware of: I found that one change that isn't 100% identically replicated under the new author name. There was an inserted paragraph with a few leading words bolded. Under the new author name, the entire paragraph was bolded. A minor problem considering the much-sought-after functinoality provided by this VBA.

Comment: In my specific case, I was trying to attribute changes from Word's `Review -> Compare -> Compare` function for differencing two documents.  As it turns out, the panel that pops up has a field for the name to which to attribute the differences found. I found that *after* a meandering search for a means to retroactively change the name attributed to changes, so hopefully it helps someone who found their way here.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to change the name *before* making tracked changes, there are [Name/Initials fields under `File -> Options`](https://erinwrightwriting.com/change-user-name-microsoft-words-track-changes/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a macro to change an author name on tracked changes and comments in a Word document (docx, docm, dotx, or dotm). The macro works for *most* tracked changes. It doesn't change the author name on updated fields, such as a table of contents.

The macro searches the entire document, not a selection, so it doesn't perfectly answer the question from @h2whoa.

Acknowledgments: @dirk-vollmar suggested editing the xml files that form the Word document. @v-v-kozlov suggested editing with a [Stream object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado) in a macro. [Jamie Garroch](http://youpresent.co.uk/remove-customui-from-a-microsoft-powerpoint-excel-or-word-file-using-vba/) suggested moving files in and out of a zip archive with [Windows Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/objects).

```
Sub ChangeTheAuthorOfTrackedChanges()
'Changes an author name on comments and tracked changes in a Word document.
'Requires a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.

    Dim objFile As Object, objShell As Object, objStream As Object
    Dim strFullName, strTempPath, strFile, strDefault
    Dim strNames, strOldAuthor, strOldInitials, strNewAuthor, strNewInitials
    Dim strOldContent, strNewContent, strFind, strReplace, varTime
    On Error Resume Next

''=> To enter the file name and author name in the code, instead of input boxes,
''=> uncomment and edit these lines. Comment out the Ask1 and Ask2 sections.
'    strFullName = _
'        "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Example - Copy.docx"
'    strOldAuthor = "John X. Doe"
'    strOldInitials = "JXD"
'    strNewAuthor = "Roe, Jane"
'    strNewInitials = "JR"

    'Asks for a file name.
    strDefault = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Example - Copy.docx"
Ask1:
    strFullName = InputBox(Prompt:="1. (Recommended) Save a copy of the " & _
        "document before running this macro." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "2. Close the document before running this macro." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "3. Type the file path and name of the document.", _
        Title:="Word document to change", _
        Default:=strDefault)
    'Warns and quits when a file name wasn't entered.
    If strFullName = strDefault Or strFullName = "" Then
        MsgBox Prompt:=vbCrLf & "A file name wasn't entered. The macro quit.", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Warns and quits when a file is open.
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFile = Documents(strFullName)
    If Not objFile Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Prompt:=vbCrLf & "The document is open." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Close the document before running the macro.", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
        Set objFile = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Warns when a file isn't a Word file.
    If Right(strFullName, 5) <> ".docx" And _
        Right(strFullName, 5) <> ".docm" And _
        Right(strFullName, 5) <> ".dotx" And _
        Right(strFullName, 5) <> ".dotm" Then
        MsgBox Prompt:="The file name doesn't have a Word file extension" & _
            vbCrLf & "(docx, docm, dotx, or dotm)." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Check the file path and name.", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
            strDefault = strFullName
        GoTo Ask1:
    End If
    'Warns when a file doesn't exist.
    If Dir(strFullName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox Prompt:=vbCrLf & "The document wasn't found." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
            & "Check the file path and name.", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
            strDefault = strFullName
        GoTo Ask1:
    End If

    'Asks for an author name to change.
    strDefault = "old name\old initials\new name\new initials"
Ask2:
    strNames = InputBox(Prompt:="Type the name and initials to change," & _
        vbCrLf & "separated by backslashes." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "For example," & vbCrLf & "John X. Doe\JXD\Roe, Jane\JR", _
        Title:="Name and initials to change", _
        Default:=strDefault)
    'Warns and quits when an author name wasn't entered.
    If strNames = strDefault Or strNames = "" Then
        MsgBox Prompt:=vbCrLf & "Names weren't entered. The macro quit.", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'Divides the entered text.
    strDefault = strNames
    strOldAuthor = Left(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") - 1)
        strNames = Mid(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") + 1)
    strOldInitials = Left(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") - 1)
        strNames = Mid(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") + 1)
    strNewAuthor = Left(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") - 1)
    strNewInitials = Mid(strNames, InStr(strNames, "\") + 1)
    'Warns when information is missing or too many backslashes are entered.
    If strOldAuthor = "" Or strOldInitials = "" Or strNewAuthor = "" Or _
        strNewInitials = "" Or InStr(strNewInitials, "\") <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Prompt:=vbCrLf & "Author names and initials weren't readable." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Check the author names, initials, and " & _
            "separator (\).", _
            Buttons:=vbExclamation
        GoTo Ask2:
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Defines a temporary folder and expands some strings.
    strTempPath = Left(strFullName, InStrRev(strFullName, "\")) & Left(Rnd(), 5)
    strOldAuthor = "author=""" & strOldAuthor & """"
    strOldInitials = "initials=""" & strOldInitials & """"
    strNewAuthor = "author=""" & strNewAuthor & """"
    strNewInitials = "initials=""" & strNewInitials & """"

    'Opens the shell and stream objects. Sets some properties.
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objStream = New ADODB.Stream
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStream.Type = adTypeText

    'Renames the Word document as a zip file and moves the folder "\word".
    Name strFullName As (strFullName & ".zip")
    MkDir strTempPath
    objShell.NameSpace(strTempPath).MoveHere (strFullName & ".zip\word")

    strFile = "First time"
    Do
        'Gets the next file name in the folder "\word" using the Dir function.
        If strFile = "First time" Then
            strFile = Dir(strTempPath & "\word\")
        Else
            strFile = Dir
        End If

        If strFile <> "" Then
            'Opens a file and copies its content.
            With objStream
                .Open
                .LoadFromFile (strTempPath & "\word\" & strFile)
                strOldContent = .ReadText
            End With
                strNewContent = strOldContent

            'Replaces author and initials.
            strFind = strOldAuthor
            strReplace = strNewAuthor
            strNewContent = Replace(strNewContent, strFind, strReplace)
            strFind = strOldInitials
            strReplace = strNewInitials
            strNewContent = Replace(strNewContent, strFind, strReplace)

            'Saves the new content, if the content changed.
            If strNewContent <> strOldContent Then
                With objStream
                    .Position = 0
                    .WriteText strNewContent
                    .SetEOS
                    .SaveToFile (strTempPath & "\word\" & strFile), _
                        adSaveCreateOverWrite
                    .Close
                End With
            Else
                objStream.Close
            End If
        End If

    'Stops looping when the Dir function doesn't return a file name.
    Loop While strFile <> ""

    'Moves the folder "\word" into the zip file.
    objShell.NameSpace(strFullName & ".zip").MoveHere (strTempPath & "\word")

    'Delays for a few seconds, then renames the zip file as a Word file.
    varTime = Time + 0.0001
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Time >= varTime
    Name (strFullName & ".zip") As strFullName
    RmDir strTempPath

    MsgBox Prompt:="The macro searched and replaced.", Buttons:=vbInformation
    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Edit Open XML** procedure described in @DirkVollmar's post can be reliably automated in VBA.  It's **a lot of work** compared to just changing the name of the author who made the revision using the Word object model, which naturally does not work at all.  In the end you will have certainly achieved coder status once you get this to work.

- As suggested by @DirkVollmar, 7-Zip is my preferred compression tool to be used with VBA.  It is free, easy to automate, the .dotx file does not need to be renamed, and you can selectively extract the various XML files without unzipping the whole thing.  See https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win004.htm for more info on automating 7-Zip.  Be sure to unzip the files in the standard Microsoft location.
- The XML files are in **UTF-8**.  UTF-8 is not directly supported by VBA, however works fine when read with ADO.  This will become clear once you have an accented character, Cyrillic name, or Kanji as an author.  See https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/863606-import-text-file-utf-8-a.html for more info on reading UTF-8 strings.
- Once read in, the XML strings can be manipulated with the stock VBA string functions like InStr(), Replace(), Mid(), and so on.  Note that the VBA IDE does not support the *display* of extended strings, but that does not mean they are not there.  Just don't expect to see Kanji in the immediate window.
- In the XML strings, look for author= and replace the quoted string immediately after, i.e. something like author="Autor" becomes author="Fritz".
- To finish up, write the files back to the temporary directory, also using ADO, then place them back into the original .dotx file using 7-Zip automation.  Be sure to delete (the `Kill` function) temporary files once they have been replaced inside the .dotx file.

Be sure to back up your .dotx files during development as you will most assuredly create files which Word will not be able to read and will claim are "damaged".  Having said that, once I got this working, I never managed to mangle a .dotx such that Word could not read it.

Comment: I disagree on **a lot of work**. When we don't consider UTF-8 and don't need something fool-proof, it can be a three liner: 
WXML = ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML;
WXML = Replace(WXML, "w:author=" & Chr(34) & "Marc Miller" & Chr(34), "w:author=" & Chr(34) & "Sue Smith" & Chr(34));
ActiveDocument.Content.InsertXML WXML.
A more elaborate version of that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727199/9700298).

Answer (score 0):

Find the replace reviewer initial only macro!!!

Sub ChangeCommentAuthor()

```
Dim J As Integer

Dim rNameFind As String
Dim rNameRePlace As String


rNameFind = InputBox("Enter the Reviwer Name to Find", vbOK)
rNameRePlace = InputBox("Enter the Reviwer name  to Replace", vbOK)

If (rNameFind = "") Then
MsgBox "Input Reviwer Name to find is empty"
Exit Sub
End If

If (rNameRePlace = "") Then
MsgBox "Input Reviwer Name to replace is empty"
Exit Sub
End If

For J = 1 To 3

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count

Dim objComment As Comment: Dim oInitial As String
If InStr(1, ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial, "") > 0 Then
oInitial = Replace(ActiveDocument.Comments(i).Initial, rNameFind, rNameRePlace)
Set objComment = ActiveDocument.Comments(i)
    objComment.Initial = oInitial

End If

Next i

Next J
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method

1. Save your document as xml
2. Open with Notepad++
3. Replace old text (Author Name) with New.
4. Save xml
5. Open xml with Word and Save in whichever format you prefer (.docx)

Comment: That looks like part of the accepted answer from July 2016. Does this add anything to that answer?

Answer (score 0):

New user. Love the post by AB9000, but can't add comment to his answer because of lack of reputation.

A snag occurs when an original insertion immediately precedes an original deletion. So my answer is to modify AB9000's code to perform the re-deletions before the re-insertions.

The snag has to do with how the ranges of the revisions are handled when adjacent text is re-inserted. (The range is expanded backwards resulting in the original insertion text being lost.)

Another unrelated change is to declare the author variables *sOldAuthor* and *sNewAuthor* at the module level and add them to the inputbox as defaults, e.g:
sOldAuthor = InputBox("Old author name?", "Comments Old Author Name"*, sOldAuthor)*
When making many changes in a doc, this avoids re-entering the authors (just hit enter).

This thread is old, but hope this helps someone.