# There is a way to change the author of revisions in a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, revision, author

I would like to know if there is a way to change the author of revisions in a document, I've found the way to change the author of comments but no for the revisions part. I've tried to find a property/method in the Revisions.object documentation to change that but I find nothing.

As I said I've already tried to do this:

```
Sub ChangeCommentCreator()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Novo As String
    Dim Corto As String
    If Selection.Comments.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No comments in your selection!", vbInformation, "Alerta"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Novo = InputBox("New author name?", "Alerta")
    Corto = InputBox("New author initials?", "Alerta")
    If Novo = "" Or Corto = "" Then
        MsgBox "The author name/initials can’t be empty.", vbInformation, "Alerta"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Selection
        For I = 1 To .Comments.Count
            .Comments(I).Author = Novo
            .Comments(I).Initial = Corto
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm going in the right way or there is just no way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisions automatically use the selected User Name in the UI. The language reference for the `Revisions`'s `Author` property states:

> Returns the name of the user who made the specified tracked change. Read-only String.

So there's no direct way using VBA and the object model to change that.

It is possible to change it by editing the underlying Word Open XML, as illustrated in the code that follows. I notice, however, that this appears to confuse Word - after running the macro no revisions are recognized in the document. Only after saving, closing and re-opening does Word "see" the revisions, again.

```
Sub ChangeAuthorName()
    Dim sWOOXML As String
    Dim findAuthor As String
    Dim replaceAuthor As String

    findAuthor = "w:author=" & Chr(34) & "Cindy Meister" & Chr(34)
    replaceAuthor = "w:author=" & Chr(34) & "unknown" & Chr(34)
    sWOOXML = ActiveDocument.content.WordOpenXML
    sWOOXML = Replace(sWOOXML, findAuthor, replaceAuthor)
    ActiveDocument.content.InsertXML sWOOXML
End Sub
```

Note that this will likely also change the author's name for comments. The more "elegant" way to do this would be to leverage an XML parser (such as MSXML) and work with the specific nodes. Or even use a package that works on the *closed* document and edits the Word Open XML. But this is the simplest way using straight Word VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer ! :) I could adapt your code to my needs and its work as i wanted.

Comment: @Satanas could you share your approach? Best regards

Answer (score 3):

I picked up Cindy Meister's suggestion and cleared the Word confusion that he reported. All revision and comment authors, creators, and lastmodied will be changed by the name entered.

```
Sub ChangeCommentAndRevisionAuthor()
    Dim j, jmax As Long
    Dim Author(99) As String
    Dim WXML, NewAuthor, FindAuthor, ReplaceAuthor As String
    Dim BNew, StatusTrackRevision As Boolean
    Dim Rev As Revision
    Dim Cmt As Comment
    
    ' set some variables and put trackrevision to false
    StatusTrackRevision = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
    jmax = -1
    ' checks and input new author name
    If ActiveDocument.Range.Revisions.count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No revisions in your document!", vbInformation, "Change comment and revision author"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    NewAuthor = InputBox("New author name?", "Change comment and revision author")
    If NewAuthor = "" Then
        MsgBox "The author name can’t be empty.", vbInformation, "Change comment and revision author"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Loop through all revisions and get all authors of revisions (maximum 100)
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        If .Revisions.count > 1000 Then
            If MsgBox("The number of revisions it large. " & .Revisions.count & vbCr & " Do you want to continue?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, "Change comment and revision author") > 1 Then Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each Rev In .Revisions
            BNew = True
            For j = 0 To jmax
                If Author(j) = Rev.Author Then
                    BNew = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If BNew Then
                jmax = jmax + 1
                If jmax > UBound(Author) Then jmax = UBound(Author)
                Author(jmax) = Rev.Author
            End If
        Next
        ' change all comments
        For Each Cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments
            Cmt.Author = NewAuthor
            Cmt.Initial = NewAuthor
        Next
    End With
    ' read XML and change all authors to the new author
    WXML = ActiveDocument.Content.WordOpenXML
    For j = 0 To jmax
        WXML = Replace(WXML, "w:author=" & Chr(34) & Author(j) & Chr(34), "w:author=" & Chr(34) & NewAuthor & Chr(34))
    Next
    ' change "last modified by" to new author
    WXML = Replace(WXML, "<cp:lastModifiedBy>" & ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(7) & "</cp:lastModifiedBy>", "<cp:lastModifiedBy>" & NewAuthor & "</cp:lastModifiedBy>")
    ' save modified XML
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertXML WXML
    ' Change Creator of Document to new author
    ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties(3) = NewAuthor
    ' restore original status of track revision
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = StatusTrackRevision
    
End Sub
```