# Open the file and save as another name

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create a new word file called "xxx_def_xxx" from selected word file called "xxx_docu_xxx".

So I select a file from dialog -> do something -> SaveAs with new file name.

It does work, but I'm getting "run time error 4160: Bad file name" if I select the file created from others, i.e., if the author is not me but another person.

I was struggling with this problem for couple of days but couldn't solve it.

Any help will be really thankful!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim fileOpen As FileDialog
    Dim docuName As String, defName As String
    Dim docu As Document
    
    Set fileOpen = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogOpen)
    With fileOpen
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Word Documents", "*.docx*"
        .Title = "Select the docu"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            docuName = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Set docu = Documents.Open(docuName)

    'do something: remove or edit some texts in the file
    
    defName = Replace(docu.Name, "docu", "def")

    docu.SaveAs docu.Path & "\" & defName
    docu.Saved = True
    docu.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't relevant anymore because your updated code works for me. Could you post more details about the error you get such as the watch value for `docu.Path & "\" & defName` for example?

Comment: I get the bad file name only if I select the word file created from others, i.e., if author is another person. Code works also for me if I select the word file created from me. How could I solve the problem?

Comment: But the name stays the same? Do you still get error 4160 or do you get another one?

Comment: If I select the file created from me, then I don't get any error 4160 more. However, If I select the file created from let's say "abc", then the file is saved as new name and the author is still "abc". Could I change the author name of the new file and not getting any error more?

Comment: Then what is the new name of the file? And how the user's name impacts the name of the file? Because I don't see why if the author name would reflect on the ".docx" name.

Comment: There is no problem with the file name. If the original file "xxx_docu_xxx" is created by "abc", then the author of the new file "xxx_def_xxx" is still "abc", although I have created (saved). I suppose I still get the error because two files have different authors.

Comment: Since this isn't error code 4160 anymore, could you give me the error code and description please?

Comment: I still only get the error code 4160, but only if I select the file created from others. If I select the file created from me, then I don't get any error more.

Comment: I don't know how it's possible that a file **with the same name** created by others returns a **bad file name** error. What is the watch value in each case?

Comment: Maybe in that case you could try to [remove/change the author property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57882809/17903744).