# In MS Word, how to change the author of track changes made after a certain date?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the problem that I was editing a Word document that already contained track changes and that had been set up by a colleague to remove "identifying information" upon save. Unfortunately I did not realize this right away so all my edits now appear as "Author" and are indistinguishable from the edits made by my colleague. However, both edits occurred 2 weeks apart, so I am wondering if it is possible to change the author of tracked changes based on the date of a change, possibly using a VBA marco.

Unfortunately I am not a programmer so was wondering if someone could point me to a script that could do the job. I found something very similar here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-we-accept-track-changes-in-a-document-by/568f0c29-f311-4661-a4a0-b57760feb4c9

but I am unable to adapt it to my needs. Instead of accepting changes after a certain date I want to change the author name from "Author" to say "Peter" in all changes made after 10 October 2023. How can this be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Pete

I tried to look at the XML files and was able to change the author name of comments as they are stored in a separate file but I was unable to pick apart the hundreds of track changes.

I also looked at these questions

[Change name of author on tracked changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225918/change-name-of-author-on-tracked-changes)

and

[There is a way to change the author of revisions in a Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867579/there-is-a-way-to-change-the-author-of-revisions-in-a-word-document)

But they do not solve my problem.

Comment: You can certainly do this through VBA, but there may an easier way: open the docx file as a zip file, extract document.xml (it seems you already did this part), open it in a simple text editor like Notepad, and find/replace the text `author="xxx" w:date="2023-10-26"` by `author="xxxnew" w:date="2023-10-26"` in the whole document (with xxx replaced by your author name, and the date by whatever date you did the changes on.) Save the file and put it back into the zip file. Now review in Word, showing changes made by xxxnew.

Comment: @Paul: I tried this but it seems that when Word removes "identifying information" it also removes the date of a change. For instance, I noticed that my edits were being anonymized about halfway through the doc, which is when I enabled saving of identifying information again. So in the first half of the xml, all changes appear as "Author" and are without date, and in the second half they appear with my name and date. I guess this means that what I am trying to do simply cannot be done. Would you agree? Kind of disappointing as this is probably a commopn problem that people run into.

Comment: Here a tracked change from the xml file where changes were anonymized when saving: `<w:ins w:id="42" w:author="Author"><w:r w:rsidRPr="00ED0AD7"><w:t>Added coccolithophores, CaCO3, variable detritus sinking speed as new model state variables and applied parameter tuning</w:t></w:r></w:ins>` and here one from the second half: `<w:del w:id="7283" w:author="Peter" w:date="2023-10-24T15:30:00Z"/>`

Comment: You are right, the date is removed. You can still do it, but only if you have the earlier version of the Word file (before your new edits) to compare to.

Comment: @Paul: I do have the original doc. So this is what I tried:
1. accept all changes in the original document (containing only the track changes made by my colleague)
2. accept all changes in the document containing the track changes of both myself and my colleague, 
3. run a document compare in Word (which resulted in a "differences" document, showing just my edit), and finally
4. run a document combine in Word, combining the original document containing track changes from my colleague only and the "differences" document created in step 3 above.
Is this what you mean?

Comment: This did indeed result in a document, where the changes made by my colleague still appeared as "Author" and mine appeared with my name. However, a lot of errors were introduces a well, in the form of duplicated words and numbers, e.g., a number that had been edited by my colleague from "0.18" to "0.32" using track changes, now appeared as "0.3232" in the combined document. As the document is quite long, it would be tedious and equally time consuming to check the entire doc for such errors as it would be to redo the entire edit. So this is also does not seem to be  a viable option...

Answer (score 0):

As you have established in the comments, Word also removes the date of an edit when identifying information is removed. So finding "all changes made after 10 October 2023" is not possible.

Also, you can not do exactly what you asked for using VBA, because the Author of a Revision is a read-only string. So you can't change the author in the edit marks.

As you still have the old document, you can certainly create a new document with only the newer edits - simply by comparing the old and the new doc. But then all older edits will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could come to an answer/solution is to follow this recipe:

1. accept all changes in the original document (containing only the track changes made by the first user)
2. accept all changes in the document containing the track changes of both users
3. run a document compare in Word which yields a document containing all differences, i.e., all edits done by 2nd user, finally
4. run a document combine in Word, combining the original document containing track changes from first user only and document containing the "differences" created in step 3 above.

This does indeed produce the desired result, namely, edits made by first user showing as "Author" and all edits done by second user (including those that had been accidentally anonymized) showing with 2nd user's name. However, at least in my case, a lot of errors had been introduced by the "combine" process (step 4), in the form of duplicated words and numbers, e.g., a number that had been edited by user 1 from "0.18" to "0.32" using track changes, now appeared as "0.3232" in the combined document. A Google search yields that this may be a common problem, so it seems that there is no perfect solution.